# iPad Kiosk Sleep Wake

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, sleep, kiosk

I have an iPad kiosk that runs a single app, I would like to conserve power by having it sleep/lock or go to a low power state (dim the screen) either on regular scheduled times (outside of business hours) or when idle for specified period of time.  The low power state on scheduled intervals will be good enough if it is simpler, as they are usually in pretty consistent use during the day.

Any tutorials out there that show how to accomplish this in Objective-C, or perhaps a few snippets to get me started?

The kiosks physically prohibit use of any of the buttons.  I looked into iOS 6 Guided Access, but I don't see how a user could unlock/wake the screen without access to the buttons.  Another solution could be Kiosk Pro Plus - but $40 bucks a pop just for sleeping doesn't seem worth it, I'd like to program it myself if feasible.

Answer (score 0):

MokiTouch is a free alternative to KioskPro and has the sleep feature. You can pay to add remote management, but that's optional.

MokiTouch.com for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions - free is good.  But it doesn't look like I can remove the mokitouch logo from the top bar (although I was able to remove all the custom buttons, which I don't need), which is a must.  The night mode is nice, but limited since I can't specify to have it off for weekends.